# Multiple answers that form one single, correct answer to the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating the best answer from more answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124912/creating-the-best-answer-from-more-answers)

What do I do if a question of mine contains two answers that when put together form the one correct answer?

The following question, [Is it possible to have multiple subdomain levels with DNS and Nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/367883/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-subdomain-levels-with-dns-and-nginx), contains two answers. Each answer addresses one aspect of my question. When both answers are combined, they form the correct answer. Is there a concept of merging answers? Or, do I just upvote both and leave the question unanswered?

Note: I'm not asking about selecting between multiple, correct answers.

Comment: One approach would be to upvote both answers, post your own answer stating that to solve the problem you needed to perform both elements described by the existing answers, then accept your answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that looks to be the best way to handle the situation. Of course, it still doesn't seem _right_ - duplicate content / not giving reputation to where reputation is deserved. I would like to see OPs with the right amount of reputation be able to merge answers. Reputation can be split and the whole Q&A library on SE would be of higher quality. But, I know that can come with a price. Anyway, I'll do what is suggested here.

Comment: You're giving reputation where reputation is deserved with that upvote arrow. Merging answers is precisely what you're doing with community wiki. Some type of automated system wouldn't give people any more reputation than the existing system. You still can't accept multiple answers, and multiple people can't get points for acceptance, merged or not.

Comment: But creating a community wiki that merges the answers into one leaves the original answers, correct? Seems redundant and a hack around the system.